# How do I persist the sort order of items in a WPF ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, sorting, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have a sortable ListBox in my application that contains a series of items with a DisplayOrder property. The items are initially sorted by DisplayOrder, but the user can reorder them by dragging and dropping.

I set the initial sort order by setting the ItemsSource of the ListBox to a CollectionViewSource with my SortDescription.

After a drag and drop operation occurs, how do I update the DisplayOrder property of the affected items?

Is this something I do in the event handlers for my drop operation, or is there a way of binding the index of the ListBox to my DisplayOrder property?

Answer (score 0):

I handled this in the code behind of the xaml file.  I passed the event action to my view model and then performed the actions in code and let the INotify update the UI with the new order.

View

```
ChangedEvent (button click / drag drop / whatever)
{
    ViewModel.MoveItemToNewLocation();

}
```

View Model

```
MoveItemToNewLocation()
{
   int newLocation = myList.IndexOf(SelectedItem); 
   int oldLocation = SelectedItem.DisplayOrder; 
   UpdateDisplayOrders(oldLocation, newLocation);
}

private void UpdateDisplayOrders(int oldlocation, int newlocation, object myitem)
{
   // Do move logic here

}
```